# Apply gradient descent on expected valued cost function

Tags: expected-value, gradient-descent, stochastic-approximation

I want to use gradient descent algorithm to minimize the Kurtosis of the error function. So, I need to calculate the gradient of the cost function $J$.

Below $\boldsymbol{w}$ and $\boldsymbol{x}$ are same length vectors, changes are in each time index $n$.
$$ \begin{array}{rcl}
e(n) &=& d(n) - \boldsymbol{w^T(n)x(n)}\\
J &=& 3E^2[e^2(n)] - E[e^4(n)]\\
\nabla J &=& 6E[e^2(n)] \frac{\partial}{\partial \boldsymbol{w}}E[e^2(n)] - \frac{\partial}{\partial \boldsymbol{w}}E[e^4(n)] \end{array}
$$

At this point I am confused how to differentiate expected value. Is it generally true that: $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \boldsymbol{w}}E[e^2(n)] = E[\frac{\partial}{\partial \boldsymbol{w}}e^2(n)]=-2E[e(n)\boldsymbol{x(n)}]=-2\boldsymbol{x(n)}E[e(n)]?$$ If not can anyone please guide how to calculate the above gradient?

Comment: You can reverse the order of integration (taking the expectation) and differentiation under certain circumstances, e.g., continuity of the expression being integrated w.r.t. the variable of differentiation and of its derivative w.r.t. the variable of differentiation.  That would appear to apply here.

Comment: Thanks a lot. However in some cases, I have seen it is approximated as $\frac{\partial}{\partial \boldsymbol{w}}E[e^2(n)] = -2\boldsymbol{x(n)}e(n)$. Is there any validity of that?